# How to edit text in a SVG file? (not programmatically)

Tags: html, svg, web, vector-graphics

I'm trying to edit a .svg file i found in a website template i recently downloaded.
The file code is this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg width="52px" height="10px" viewBox="0 0 52 10" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <title>Stacked</title>
    <desc>Created with Sketch.</desc>
    <defs></defs>
    <g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" font-size="12" font-family="ProximaNova-Bold, Proxima Nova" font-weight="bold">
        <text id="Stacked" fill="#000000">
            <tspan x="0" y="9">Stacked</tspan>
        </text>
    </g>
</svg>
```

What i want is to simply change the text. I was expecting to do it by changing the inner text of the TSPAN tag you can see at the end of the file. But nothing happens, even if I change text from a SVG editor.

So, my question is: what is the proper way to achieve my goal? Is it even possible to change text in a SVG file?

Answer (score 0):

This is your code, and it should work (please run the code):

```css
svg{border:1px solid;overflow:visible}
```

```html
<svg width="52px" height="10px" viewBox="0 0 52 10" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <title>Stacked</title>
    <desc>Created with Sketch.</desc>
 
    <g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" font-size="12" font-family="ProximaNova-Bold, Proxima Nova" font-weight="bold">
        <text id="Stacked" fill="#000000">
            <tspan x="0" y="9">Stacked edited</tspan>
        </text>
    </g>
</svg>
```

As an observation: the SVG canvas is very small so large part of the text is not visible unless you add `overflow:visible`for the svg.

Comment: I would do the same to change the text! But the template creator said it's impossible to simply change the text, he says I have to use a brand new svg image. Changing the text in the file (like you did) does not affect what i see on the browser, i even tried to rebuild and rebundle my app entirely. Have you some place in mind where i can check something more to provide usefull informations in my question?

Comment: @moro91 thank you for your comment. Maybe your SVG is in a larger context, maybe there is a script controlling the text content of the tspan.

Comment: Thank you for your quick and usefull answer. I'm trying to work on the context, that's the exact thing i was thinking of. I'll keep you updated!